# Replace content between two words

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to replace the content between two words using php.  The content between the two words is different so I can't use tradition str_replace.  I want to replace the content between two words for example:

```
I would like to replace **some string of text** between two words
```

change to:

```
I would like to replace between two words
```

You can see that I removed all the wording between "some" and "text".  Again I cannot use regular str_replace because the text between the two words may differ. For example it may say:

```
I would like to replace **some words of text** between two words
```

change to:

```
I would like to replace between two words
```

Comment: `$txt = preg_quote('some string of text'); $new = preg_replace("/$txt/", 'new text', $old);` doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex is simple: `/some .*? text/`

Just replace it with the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, only the inner part of your string changes. If that is the case it's rather trivial, because you already have the solution: You do not need to replace it, but you just need to not take it over:

```
$result = substr($string, 0, $startlen) . substr($string, -$endlen);
```

Probably this helps you to find some more "resolution angles" for such problems.